# Cumulative count using grouping, sorting, and condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want Cumulative count of zero only in column c grouped by column a and sorted by b if other number the count reset to 1
this a sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'c':[10,0,0,5,1,0,1,0]}
)
```

i try next code that work but if zero appear more than one time shift function didn't depend on new value and need to run more than one time depend on count of zero series

```
df.loc[df.c == 0 ,'n'] = df.n.shift(1)+1
```

i try next code it done with small data frame but when try with large data take a long time and didn't finsh

```
for ind in df.index:
    if df.loc[ind,'c'] == 0 :
        df.loc[ind,'new'] =  df.loc[ind-1,'new']+1
    else :
        df.loc[ind,'new'] = 1
```

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
               'b':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
               'c':[10,0,0,5,1,0,1,0]}
```

The desired result

```
    a   b   c   n
0   1   1   10  1
1   1   2   0   2
2   1   3   0   3
3   1   4   5   1
4   2   1   1   1
5   2   2   0   2
6   2   3   1   1
7   2   4   0   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `cumsum` to create a group variable and then use `groupby.cumcount` to create the new column:

```
df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)

df['n'] = df['c'].groupby([df.a, df['c'].ne(0).cumsum()]).cumcount() + 1

df
   a  b   c  n
0  1  1  10  1
1  1  2   0  2
2  1  3   0  3
3  1  4   5  1
4  2  1   1  1
5  2  2   0  2
6  2  3   1  1
7  2  4   0  2
```

Comment: You should probably also group by a (although the logic is not fully clear)

Comment: @mozway Good point. Didn't read the first part of the question :)

Comment: @Psidom thank you your answer very clear and work with large data